# Unknown Host Exception Yet Website Is Accessible

Tags: java, spring, rest, unknown-host

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA to implement the Spring Guide for consuming REST services

https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/

When I run the Application class I receive the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: 
I/O error on GET request for "https://gturnquist-quoters.cfapps.io/api/random": 
gturnquist-quoters.cfapps.io; 
nested exception is 
java.net.UnknownHostException: gturnquist-quoters.cfapps.io
```

The URL itself (https://gturnquist-quoters.cfapps.io/api/random) opens fine in a browser and my HTTP Proxy settings in IntelliJ can connect to the site without any issues.  Why would an UnknownHostException be thrown here?

Comment: Can you just try hitting over HTTP instead of HTTPS

Comment: Try to launch your application with the VM option "-Djava.net.useSystemProxies=true".

Comment: Did you got any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Hey I know this is a bit late, but here is what I had to do to resolve this issue. Even if you are using system proxies, for whatever reason, using this type of GET request requires you to build out a proxy to use in the call, like so.

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WV5V.png)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please edit your answer by adding a code sample and please take a look at this article : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557